# JHipster - This is an existing project

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to make a JHipster project from scratch. I've done this before, but for some reason it's not working anymore. When I go to my console, navigate to a blank folder and use "yo jhipster" it responds with:

"This is an existing project, using the configuration from your .yo-rc.json file

to re-generate the project..."

The thing I don't understand is why it's giving me this message for a brand new project in a completely blank folder that has been untouched by JHipster thus far. Anyone know where this is coming from?

Thanks.

Comment: The .yo-rc.json file starts with a dot, I'm quite sure you have one at the root of your folder, but it's a hidden file, that's why you don't see it

Comment: You may have an existing jHipster project in your path.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you have a problem in your app.jh

I had the same problem when I try to change de language.

Try to set de default options first and then change it. Remember to remove the .yo-rc.json file first.